# Connection Refused Error in RabbitMQ with amqplib npm module

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I am new to RabbitMQ and I am trying out the simple example in Nodejs.

```
const amqp    = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672',function(err, 
conn) {
    console.log("Enter in callback",conn);
    if (err) {
      console.error("[AMQP]", err.message);
      return err;
    }
    conn.on("error", function(err) {
      if (err.message !== "Connection closing") {
        console.error("[AMQP] conn error", err.message);
      }
    });
    conn.on("close", function() {
      console.error("[AMQP] reconnecting");
      return;
    });

    console.log("[AMQP] connected");
    amqpConn = conn;
    callback(null,"Success");
  });
```

I am seeing 'conn error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:15672' error. Please let me know where I am doing wrong and I can access it from web using http://localhost:15672.

Thanks

Comment: Did you start the rabbitmq server?

Comment: Yes, I did using 'invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start' command on Ubuntu, even restarted the server multiple times with 'sudo service rabbitmq-server restart' command.

Answer (score 1):

`15672` is the HTTP API port. You should connect to port `5672`, which is the default AMQP TCP port.

Please note that the documentation on rabbitmq.com is very comprehensive and worth reading carefully. [The network troubleshooting document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html) could have assisted you in figuring this out.

Comment: Thanks its working now. I am using AWS SAM local which runs inside docker, so I should be using my system IP address instead of localhost when connecting to RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Just switching from

amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672

to

amqp://127.0.0.1:5672 worked for me.